# LINQ and paging with a listview

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, listview, paging

I have a page with a listview control and a datapager control. The listviews datasource is set programatically using this code:

```
Dim dal as new dalDataContext
Dim bookmarks = From data In dal.getData(userid)
listview1.DataSource = bookmarks
listview1.DataBind()
```

When i test this page in a browser it comes up with the error: 'ListView with id 'listview1' must have a data source that either implements ICollection or can perform data source paging if AllowPaging is true.'

How can i implement paging in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
listview1.DataSource = bookmarks.ToArray()
```

I had the same problem this week.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Very quick response. Cannot believe it was something that simple.

Comment: One minor problem, i have to click the page numbers twice before it goes to the next page or previous page. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Better yet use `ToArray()` - it's slightly more lightweight if you don't actually need full functionality of `List` (such as adding new items) - which you do not here; and arrays implement `ICollection` (and `IList`) otherwise.

Comment: briggins5, sounds like a problem with the code that keeps track of the current page/binds data, best suited for another post if you're still stuck

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I'll ask a new question if i can't fix it myself.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to the click-twice problem that the OP subsequently encountered - move the Databind to the OnPreRender event handler:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe create a page properties changing and bindlistview there.

```
protected void lv_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    //set current page startindex, max rows and rebind to false
    DataPager dp = lvNews.FindControl("lvDataPager1") as DataPager;
    dp.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);

    BindListView();
}
```